# Laravel - Office365 - MapiExceptionSendAsDenied

Tags: laravel, office365, exchange-server

We have a Laravel-based intranet application that sends email notifications for a number of different systems within it. Currently, we connect to an on-prem Exchange Server (2010) via the SwiftMailer Library and the SMTP driver provided by Laravel to send the notifications from a number of non-existant addresses, i.e. `SomeHelpdesk@domain.com`, `SomeOtherHelpdesk@domain.com` etc. These addresses are not linked in any way to a physical mailbox.

We are now migrating to Office365 and I am having trouble setting Laravel up so that we do not have to alter the way notifcations are sent as described above.

I have used this configuration in the .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=Intranet@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I got this to work by creating a new Mailbox (same as in `MAIL_USERNAME`) in Office365 and using the credentials in the config as above. This works when sending as the email address configured in `MAIL_USERNAME`, however, when **trying to *send as*** another address we get an error message:

> Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0  STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;
>   Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message
>   Cannot submit message

I have been advised by our Sys Admin team that we cannot grant `SendAs` permissions for an address that is not linked to an account in Office365 (is this correct?).

I have been reading through the Microsoft documentation and found [this item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3) which presents three different options for sending mail from an application. From my understanding, our current setup is using Option A.

My question is will using the Direct Mail option solve my problem and/or how have any of you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this Mail-Driver:
https://github.com/motze92/office365-mail

This send's email from the Graph Rest Api and works better than the Office365 SMTP what gives many times unexpected timeouts and errors.